# Jquery SVG transformation strange behavior

Tags: jquery, svg, transform, jquery-svg

I'm trying to rotate an SVG `<polygon>` (or any other element) using this:

```
var svg = new $.svg._wrapperClass($('#test'));
$(svg._svg).animate({svgTransform: 'rotate(720,100,100)'}, 2000);​
```

The polygon really changes its angle, but with some strange trajectory of moving.
Please, go to this link to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/ExaBP/

My goal is to make the polygon spinning around its center.

Comment: try to render the shapes using other application, like [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and see if anything changes.

Comment: The movement looks like that animation is not only animating through the 720, but also through the x and y values. that is why it is a spiral.

Comment: Andrew, you've seen the code. There is only rotate.

Comment: Rendering in Inkskape don't help. Same picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the rotation center your polygon is on coord(0,0) > look at the points :

```
points="38.8313,102.22 42.1242,104.613 45.4171,107.005 44.1593,110.876 42.9015,114.747 38.8313,114.747 34.7611,114.747 33.5034,110.876 32.2456,107.005 35.5384,104.613"
```

So, if you use (cx,cy) for the rotation in **animate**, these parameters are also animate, from 0 to 100 then to 0.

You must change the center before and after the animation.

But here, I think you need a different approch :

- Try to create your SVG directly in the HTML or JS
- **or** try to modify the origin of coordonates in your drawing program before exportation.

Comment: Do you know how to modify the coords right way in Inskape or CorelDRAW?

Comment: I can't make svg's in html or js because my real svg is much more complex than polygon with box.

Comment: Indeed... Another solution is set the polygon with center an move it after at the right position in your composition. See at : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace
And, at least, you have an explaination, no?